# How to stop device.starttimer xamarin forms on button click?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I have two buttons Start/Stop and start works fine because it starts at the beginning each time start is clicked, which is what I want. But I'm new to xamarin forms and don't entirely understand how to stop device.starttimer.

This is what I have currently and it's not working. (don't worry about the sound stuff)

```
//timer
    bool shouldRun = false;
    private void timer()
    {
        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
        {
            // Do something
            label.Text = "Time is up!";
            //shows start button instead of stop button
            startButton.IsVisible = true;
            //hides stop button
            stopButton.IsVisible = false;
            return shouldRun;
        });
    }

    private void STOPButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //shows start button instead of stop button
        startButton.IsVisible = true;
        //hides stop button
        stopButton.IsVisible = false;
        //stops timer
        shouldRun = false;
        //stops sound
    }

    private void STARTButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //hides start button
        startButton.IsVisible = false;
        //shows stop button instead of start button
        stopButton.IsVisible = true;

        //starts timer from beginning

        timer();
        //starts sound from beginning
    }
```

Comment: When you return `false` from the Func<bool> the timer is stopped.

Comment: That's what I thought but the Stop button isn't working when I declare shouldRun = false.

Comment: After you declare `shouldRun = false` in the stop button, the timer delegate will run one more time at the end of its 3 second timer, if you do not want the label being set to "Time is up!", then you would need to perform a check of `shouldRun` before that and jump over that assignment (or perform an early exit, `return false`).

Answer (score 2):

1. You add a cancellation token source to the view running the timer

   private CancellationTokenSource cancellation;
2. Adapt your StopButton code as follows:

   ```
   private void STOPButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       startButton.IsVisible = true;
       //hides stop button
       stopButton.IsVisible = false;
       //stops timer
       if (this.cancellation != null)
           Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
       shouldRun = false;
   }
   ```
3. Finally in your timer delegate you create the cancellation token source

   ```
   CancellationTokenSource cts = this.cancellation = new CancellationTokenSource();
   Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), () =>
   {
       if (this.cancellation != null)
           Interlocked.Exchange(ref this.cancellation, new CancellationTokenSource()).Cancel();
       // Do something
       label.Text = "Time is up!";
       //shows start button instead of stop button
       startButton.IsVisible = true;
       //hides stop button
       stopButton.IsVisible = false;
       return shouldRun;
   });
   ```

Basically it is quite similar to the bool flag method, SushiHangover mentioned in his comment. However a cancellation source is thread safe, so you don't run into nasty race conditions when stopping your timer from a different thread.